# dplyr Running count of unique entries

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df <- readr::read_table("
date        caseID  subjectID   yr
2018-12-12  47582   000c15d0    4   
2018-12-12  47582   000c15d0    4   
2018-12-12  47584   000c15d0    4   
2018-12-12  47591   000c15d0    4   
2018-12-12  47594   000c15d0    4   
2018-12-12  47610   000c15d0    4   
2016-02-25  5222    0038263c    4   
2016-02-25  5222    0038263c    4   
2016-02-25  5223    0038263c    4   
2016-02-25  5223    0038263c    4")
```

Given a data frame as above, I need to create a column `n_tot` that creates a running count of the number of total entries for each `subjectID` and a column `n_case` that is a running count of all unique `caseID` entries. The result would like:

```
date        caseID subjectID   yr n_tot n_case
2018-12-12  47582   000c15d0    4     1      1
2018-12-12  47582   000c15d0    4     2      1
2018-12-12  47584   000c15d0    4     3      2
2018-12-12  47591   000c15d0    4     4      3
2018-12-12  47594   000c15d0    4     5      4
2018-12-12  47610   000c15d0    4     6      5
2016-02-25  5222    0038263c    4     1      1
2016-02-25  5222    0038263c    4     2      1
2016-02-25  5223    0038263c    4     3      2
2016-02-25  5223    0038263c    4     4      2
```

I have the code:

```
df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(subjectID, yr) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(date, caseID, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(n_case = dplyr::n_distinct(caseID)) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup(caseID) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(n_tot = seq(dplyr::n())) %>%
  dplyr::select(date, caseID, subjectID, yr, n_tot, n_case)
```

But this is producing:

```
date       caseID   subjectID  yr n_tot n_case
2018-12-12  47582   000c15d0    4     1      5
2018-12-12  47582   000c15d0    4     2      5
2018-12-12  47584   000c15d0    4     3      5
2018-12-12  47591   000c15d0    4     4      5
2018-12-12  47594   000c15d0    3     5      5
2018-12-12  47610   000c15d0    4     6      5
2016-02-25  5222    0038263c    4     1      2
2016-02-25  5222    0038263c    4     2      2
2016-02-25  5223    0038263c    4     3      2
2016-02-25  5223    0038263c    4     4      2
```

I have tried various options (such as `seq(n_distinct(caseID))`, but I can not get anything to produce the desired result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to give the result you are after

```
df %>%
  group_by(subjectID) %>% 
  mutate(
    n_tot = row_number(),
    n_case=cumsum(!duplicated(caseID))
  )
```

We use `duplicated` to see if the case ID is new or not, and then use `cumsum()` to get a running count of new cases.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you. I noticed you removed `arrange(date, caseID, .by_group = TRUE)`. The point of this was to be sure that the running count was in order of increasing dates and then increased caseID. Can I still be sure this happening without it?

Comment: I was just going by the behavior you described in the text. I didn't read your code. If you need the values to be sorted by date then you should explicitly arrange them.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of other options would be using `match`+ `unique`  and `dense_rank` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(subjectID) %>% 
  mutate(n_tot = row_number(),
        n_case = match(caseID, unique(caseID)))
        #n_case = dense_rank(caseID)

#    date       caseID subjectID    yr n_tot n_case
#   <date>      <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <int>  <int>
# 1 2018-12-12  47582 000c15d0      4     1      1
# 2 2018-12-12  47582 000c15d0      4     2      1
# 3 2018-12-12  47584 000c15d0      4     3      2
# 4 2018-12-12  47591 000c15d0      4     4      3
# 5 2018-12-12  47594 000c15d0      4     5      4
# 6 2018-12-12  47610 000c15d0      4     6      5
# 7 2016-02-25   5222 0038263c      4     1      1
# 8 2016-02-25   5222 0038263c      4     2      1
# 9 2016-02-25   5223 0038263c      4     3      2
#10 2016-02-25   5223 0038263c      4     4      2
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you. I noticed you removed `arrange(date, caseID, .by_group = TRUE)`. The point of this was to be sure that the running count was in order of increasing dates and then increased caseID. Can I still be sure this happening without it?

Comment: That should be added in if your data is not ordered always.